# Handling PHP erros with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Trying to submit a form via ajax and handle the PHP errors,

here is my form

```
<div class="boxFocus">
   <?php echo $message_text;  echo $errors;  ?>
   <form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/includes/form-handler.php" id="contactfrm" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="name">Name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter name"  title="Please enter your name (at least 2 characters)" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Email</label>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" title="Please enter a valid email address"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="phone">Phone</label>
         <input name="phone" class="form-control required digits" type="tel" id="phone" size="30" value="" placeholder="Enter email phone" title="Please enter a valid phone number (at least 10 characters)" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="comments">Comments</label>
         <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="comments" cols="3" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message…" title="Please enter your message (at least 10 characters)" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="result"></div>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitform"> Submit</button>
   </form>
   <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery

```
 $("#submitform").click(function(){
   // e.preventDefault();
    //alert("yo");
    var form_data = $("#contactfrm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ltlcreation-new/wordpress/wp-content/themes/LTLCreation/includes/form-handler.php",
        data: form_data,
        error: function(){
            alert("failed");
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
        },
        })
    });
```

and here is the form handler

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  //include validation class
  include 'validate.class.php';

  //assign post data to variables
  $name = @($_POST['name']);
  $email = @($_POST['email']);
  $message = @($_POST['message']);
  $phone = @$_POST["phone"];

  //echo $name, $email, $message, $phone;


  //start validating our form
  $v = new validate();
  $v->validateStr($name, "name", 3, 75);
  $v->validateEmail($email, "email");
  $v->validateStr($message, "message", 5, 1000);
  $v->validateStr($phone, "phone", 11, 13);

  if(!$v->hasErrors()) {

        $to = "lukelangfield001@googlemail.com";
        $subject = "Website contact form ";

        $mailbody = $message . "\n" . "from " . $name . "\n" . $phone;
        $headers = "From: $email";

        mail($to, $subject, $mailbody, $headers);

        echo "success";

    } else {
    //set the number of errors message
    $message_text = $v->errorNumMessage();

    //store the errors list in a variable
    $errors = $v->displayErrors();

    //get the individual error messages
    $nameErr = $v->getError("name");
    $emailErr = $v->getError("email");
    $messageErr = $v->getError("message");
    $phoneErr = $v->getError("phone");

   echo $message_text;  echo $errors;  
  }//end error check

}// end isset
```

When I fire the form-handler without Ajax it works correctly and returns me the validation errors, I wanted to know how I can pass these back through to the page and update the content to display the errors. The alerts were just for when I was attempting to use Ajax, in the future I will update the div class result with the result

Sorry if this is a basic question, just struggling to get my head around ajax as previously I've been using malsup but wanted to do this myself.

Comment: You have to uncomment `e.preventDefault();` line as well as define `e` parameter

Answer (score 1):

You don't have expected result, because you're sending the form.

You have to use the `event` parametr in "on-click" function and prevent a default behaviour i.e. sending form.
Simple version of code may look like this:

```
   $("#submitform").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     window.console.log('will not submit a form');
     // ajax request
   });
```

Your code should look like this:

```
   $("#submitform").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     var form_data = $("#contactfrm").serialize();
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ltlcreation-new/wordpress/wp-content/themes/LTLCreation/includes/form-handler.php",
        data: form_data,
        error: function(){
            alert("failed");
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
        },
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the contents of the returned data by changing your `success` callback like...

```
success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
    //do stuff here like add messages in your <div>
},
```

Once you have checked the actual output, maybe you can update your question for us to see and help you more with the output.

Answer (score 0):

I can wrap you PHP snippet in try/catch block, if PHP fails you can always pack an error in a HTML you want and return it to Browser.